# How to apply annotations for Sum() on multiple django models?

Tags: django

I have three django models: ProjectName,ProjectBudget and ProjectActualCost.

ProjectName stores the project name (ie Project X).
ProjectBudget stores the project_name(as a foreign key(FK)),budget_name and the total_budget and date for each budget. ie (Project X, Hotel,600),(Project X, Rental,500). '600' refers to $600.
ProjectActualCost stores each cost as it is incurred(itemized costs) (ie Hotel: 100, Rental: 50, Food:100) and its date. So it stores the 'project_name'(as FK),'budget_name'(as FK),actual_used and date.
ie (Project X,Hotel,100,10/03/2019),(Project X,Hotel,100,10/06/2019),
(Project X,Rental,50,04/10/2019)

I'm trying to render the 'Project Name', 'Budget Name','Total Budget', 'Total Used'and 'Difference' in an html table. Project Name', 'Budget Name','Total Budget', 'Total Used' are rendering correctly,but 'Difference' displays inflated amounts as shown below.

Models:

```
class ProjectName(models.Model):
   project_name = models.CharField('Name',max_length = 15,blank = False)

  def __str__(self):
    return self.project_name 

class ProjectBudget(models.Model):
   project_name = models.ForeignKey(ProjectName,on_delete = models.CASCADE, 
          null = True)
   budget_name = models.CharField('Budget Name'max_length = 50
   total_budget =  models.DecimalField('Total Budget',max_digits = 9,decimal_places=2)

   def __str__(self):
    return self.budget_name 

class ProjectActualCost(models.Model):
   project_name = models.ForeignKey(ProjectName,on_delete = models.CASCADE, null = True)
   cost_description = models.ForeignKey(ProjectBudget,on_delete = models.CASCADE,null=True)
   actual_used = models.DecimalField('Actual Used',max_digits = 15,decimal_places = 2)
```

Views:

```
def budgetview(request,project_id):
  budget_items = ProjectBudget.objects.filter(project_name_id=project_id).annotate( actual_cost=Sum('projectactualcost__actual_used'),
difference=Sum('total_budget')-Sum('projectactualcost__actual_used'))

    budget_template = "budget_view.html"

    context = {"budget_items":budget_items}

    return render(request,budget_template,context)
```

budget_view.html:

```
<table>
 <thead>
   <tr>
   <th>Project Name</th>
   <th>Budget Name</th>
   <th>Total Budget</th>
   <th>Total Used</th>
   <th>Difference</th>

   </tr>

 <tbody>
    {% for item in budget_items%}
   <tr> 
        <td>{{item.project_name}}</td>
        <td>{{item.cost_description}}</td>
        <td>{{item.total_budget}}</td>
        <td>{{item.actual_cost}}</td>
        <td>{{item.difference}}</td>

   </tr>
   {%endfor%}

 </tbody>
 </table>
```

I'm expecting to see:

```
Project Name|Budget Name | Total Budget| Total Used| Difference
 Project X     Hotel        600            200        400    
 Project X     Rental       500            50         450
```

But when i render budget_view.html, I get:

```
 Project Name|Budget Name | Total Budget| Total Used|Difference|
 Project X   |  Hotel     |   600       |    300    | 900  
 Project X   |  Rental    |   500       |    100    | 600
```

How do i correctly make calculations for multiple sum() annotations?Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is will not work because you are aggregating all rows in the ProjectBudget table. Try adding a property that handles the difference calculation for each ProjectBudget instance.

```
class ProjectBudget(models.Model):
    project_name = models.ForeignKey(ProjectName, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                     null=True)
    budget_name = models.CharField('Budget Name', max_length=50)
    total_budget = models.DecimalField('Total Budget', max_digits=9, decimal_places=2)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.budget_name

    @property
    def used_difference(self):
        return self.total_budget - self.projectactualcost_set.filter(cost_description=self.id)\
            .aggregate(Sum('actual_used')).get('actual_used__sum')
```

And update the template

```
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Project Name</th>
        <th>Budget Name</th>
        <th>Total Budget</th>
        <th>Total Used</th>
        <th>Difference</th>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
    {% for item in budget_items %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ item.project_name }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.budget_name }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.total_budget }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.actual_cost }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.used_difference }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Which gives me

```
 Project Name|Budget Name | Total Budget| Total Used|Difference|
 Project X   |  Hotel     |   600       |    250    | 350  
 Project X   |  Rental    |   500       |    100    | 400
```